# NearProtocol Rust contracts Boilerplate Code

Tags: rust, code-snippets, nearprotocol

Can I have the boilerplate for a rust contract using vscode? Just the basic to get things started. To configure a snippet we press ctrl + shift + p, then select "configure user snippets". Need a snippet for .rs and .toml files. Just press the first few letters and get the full boilerplate ready.

Answer (score 1):

Start typing "near protocol" for the snippet to show.

About the rust snippet: Not all projects will need serde::{serialize, deserialize}. But it shouldn't be much of a problem to have it declared anyway.

.toml snippet:

```
    "Near BoilerPlate Cargo.toml": {
        "prefix": "near protocol",
        "body": [
            "",
            "[lib]",
            "crate-type = [\"cdylib\", \"rlib\"]",
            "",
            "[dependencies]",
            "near-sdk = \"3.1.0\"",
            "",
            "[profile.release]",
            "codegen-units = 1",
            "# Tell `rustc` to optimize for small code size.",
            "opt-level = \"z\"",
            "lto = true",
            "debug = false",
            "panic = \"abort\"",
            "overflow-checks = true",
            "",
        ],
        "description": "Boilerplate for Creating a rust near contract",
    },
```

rust snippet:

```
"NEAR BoilerPlate lib.rs": {
        "prefix": "near protocol",
        "body": [
            "use near_sdk::borsh::{self, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};",
            "#[allow(unused_imports)]",
            "use near_sdk::{env, near_bindgen};",
            "use near_sdk::serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};",
            "",
            "",
            "near_sdk::setup_alloc!();",
            "",
            "",
            "#[near_bindgen]",
            "#[derive(Clone, Default, Serialize, Deserialize, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]",
            "#[serde(crate = \"near_sdk::serde\")]",
            "pub struct Contract {",
            "",
            "}",
            "",
            "#[near_bindgen]",
            "impl Contract{",
            "",
            "}",
        ],
        "description": "BoilerPlate for Creating a near contract"
    },
```